# Keeping kestrel alive when using Quartz.Net

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, quartz.net

I have a Quartz Job running in the Web API.

For the Job to keep running, Kestrel needs to stay alive. But IIS keeps shutting Kestrel Shuts Down if not in use and starts again when the application is requested.

Is it possible to stop kestrel from shutting down during the shutdown event:

`IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping`

Comment: You obviously only provide half of the information... Kestrel by itself doesn't shut down when idle, IIS does, which means you are using IIS (which you don't mention at all in your post). There are certain options in IIS to push it back, but in the end: There is no guarantee that the process won't be killed by IIS (or other reverse proxy, no idea how its with nginx etc.). And no, for IIS it's not possible to completely prevent it. Background task and schedulers are best run as console application not as web application for that reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following @Tseng recommendation, instead of hosting in IIS, I'm running it as a windows service.

I used this post:

http://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-host-your-aspnet-core-in-a-windows-service/

as a reference.